# How to solve net::ERR_ABORTED 404 in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently towards the end of my project but there is one error I am receiving still. I cannot seem to figure out why I am receiving the error:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)".

Below is my file layout, server.js and the script tag. I have my layout the same as all the other projects I have made in the past but for some reason this error keeps popping.

server.js

```
"use strict";

// DEPENDENCIES
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const path = require("path");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const logger = require("morgan");

var createError = require("http-errors");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const favicon = require("serve-favicon");

// ROUTES REQUIRED
const main = require("./routes/main");
const about = require("./routes/about");
const contact = require("./routes/contact");
const profile = require("./routes/profile");
const pricing = require("./routes/pricing");
const help = require("./routes/help");
const login = require("./routes/login");
const signup = require("./routes/signup");
const forgot_password = require("./routes/forgot-password");

// PORT
const port = 3000;
const app = express();

// COOKIES AND SESSION
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// DATABASE
require("./config/database.js");

// PASSPORT AUTHENTICATION
require("./config/passport.js");

// VIEWS SETUP
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname + "/views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("view cache", false);

// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(favicon(__dirname + "/public/favicon.ico"));
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")));
app.use(flash());

// ROUTES

app.use("/", main);
app.use("/about", about);
app.use("/contact", contact);
// PRICING
app.use("/pricing", pricing);
// PROFILE
app.use("/profile", profile);
app.use("/help", help);
app.use("/login", login);
app.use("/signup", signup);
app.use("/forgot-password", forgot_password);

// Logout
app.get("/logout", function (req, res) {
  res.clearCookie("connect.sid");
  res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, (err, done) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log({ message: "success!" });
  } else {
    return err;
  }
});
```

home.ejs(home page layout with scripts.)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <section class="ad-analytics">
      <div class="container-fluid ad-analytics__contain">
        <div class="row ad-analytics__row">
          <div class="col-md-6" id="meetings-img-holder">
            <!-- bg-img holder -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 ad-analytics__textbox">
            <div class="col-sm-12 ad-analytics__info">
              <h1 class="h2">Analytical Precision</h1>
              <p>
                Getting ahead of the curve is the best way to scale above the
                compeititon. With our machine learning tools, you can leverage
                your data and get real insight on what your customers want from
                you.
              </p>
              <a
                class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm"
                href="/machine-learning"
                role="button"
                >Get Started</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <%- include('partials/footer.ejs') %> 
    <%- include('partials/scripts.ejs') %>
  </body>
</html>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(Inside partials/script.js)

<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script type="javascript" src="/server.js"></script>
```

File Layout

[image]

Comment: What is the url path you’re trying to access?

Comment: @Lior Pollak it is the root url. It would be localhost:3000/server.js but whenever I spin up the server it give me the message I put in the title. I am not sure if it has something to do with other routes in the server or not.

Comment: why are you passing the server initialization file to the page ?, if you're trying to load a script file it should be inside /public folder

Comment: @DivineSoul Soul so even my routes folder should be in the public folder including the server page since it’s static? I tried moving the serverJs yesterday into public but I still got net::ABORTED flag. I will try again later tonight moving all the routes in there. I made smaller projects throughout a class that had the server initializer outside of a static path way, and the DevTools never triggered an abort 404, which is why I am confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `<script>` tags to import server side files, like for an example `server.js`, this file is used to run the node server

let's say you make a script for home page, you need to save it inside `/public` and the send it to client to be interpreted by the browser by adding it to `partials/scripts.ejs`

example

```
<script type="javascript" src="/home_script.js"></script>
```

the path would be

```
public/home_script.js
```

Edit:
it feels like you're still a bit confused so i'll take a example

in `server.js` you have

```
const main = require("./routes/main");
app.use("/", main);
```

think about the file `main.js` like taking a function from `server.js` and moving it to a single file

now in `main.js` i'm guessing you have a function like this:

```
router.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
 res.render('home.ejs')

})
```

the code above is part of server side code and shouldn't be sent to the user(the client)

now inside `home.ejs`
you have your partials and then a section for scripts

```
<script type="javascript" src="/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="/home_script.js"></script>
```

this file `home_script` should contains stuff that you want to do once the page arrives the `user` (we call this client side)

as an example:

if you have button and you want to do something when you click you write that part of javascript inside home_script.js

Comment: That is exactly what It was. My last question would be that I have multiple routes for different things (signup, login, etc). I am not getting any errors when I switched out my server.js for the my main route in the scripts tag. Based off your description, I would need to add every route js file I have into scripts correct? I have them all in a routing file by the way.